# Rails Devise parameters not written to DB (only on server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm maintaining a Rails application that is about 2 years old. In the last months, users reported errors when trying to create a new user account (previously no issues). Looking through the logs, I found out that the Devise user accounts are being created without an email address and username. That should not be possible, since both are required fields. The email is the unique identifier for a user, so this obviously breaks all sorts of things.

I tested locally and could not reproduce the issue. I then tested it on the server - there, I am able to see in the logs that when a user is created, the two parameters are not included in the INSERT.

**Local**

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0JW4oOs+D9plubsIxDxO2N8RjiQtCpuSNE92hJqCQ/N6QkYTFPqnSxmSeqhiKBFFySCzRgG3L+TbQJKZCF9zmQ==", "user"=>{"username"=>"jantesting1", "email"=>"jantesting1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "team_code"=>"cat45", "num_team_members"=>"0", "accept_terms"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
##### current_user does not exist #####
 Team Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`code` = 'cat45' LIMIT 1
 ↳ app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:4
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 ↳ app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5
 User Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'jantesting1@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
 ↳ app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5
 User Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `encrypted_password`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES ('jantesting1@gmail.com', '$2a$11$TiHmwBmI/FmcSXk.ypKu2esrr9nKGoEpjiDPaxQanlD7n6ZQx3/T2', '2020-01-29 18:05:22', '2020-01-29 18:05:22', 'jantesting1')
 ↳ app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5
  (0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

**Server**

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LrjPR95LZzIEFQH5PEWpkX0GI/q4xnJp+UVmT5gcjbxlbH8IsBbETL0l7xg5w6c33dx7yBZ1ztQVhpvigDjjgg==", "user"=>{"username"=>"jantesting1", "email"=>"jantesting1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "team_code"=>"yak44", "num_team_members"=>"3", "accept_terms"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
##### current_user does not exist #####
  Team Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`code` = 'yak44' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'jantesting1@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  User Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`encrypted_password`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('$2a$11$3MBvOEWhpb7IhoH8tl7YXemCZHWxea0FA/b8Ww90m3oEx.hYFJwuK', '2020-01-30 12:21:45', '2020-01-30 12:21:45')
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
```

What's more, as far as I can tell, this issue started occurring recently, without any changes to the codebase. I have checked that both are are the same git state, that all of the relevant libraries are at the same versions (it's mostly in the Gemfile anyways), etc. I've git checked out an older version of the code, and the issue still persists there.

Finally, and perhaps most confusingly, some users have been able to create accounts in the last couple weeks (ie where the email is not blank). But not most. And not me.

Any suggestions on where to look?

**application_controller**

```
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :team_code, :num_team_members, :accept_terms])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:login, :email, :password, :remember_me, :num_team_members])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password])
    end
```

**registrations_controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    if Team.where(code: params[:user][:team_code]).exists?
      super
      if current_user
        current_user.team = Team.find_by_code(params[:user][:team_code])
        current_user.save!
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path, :flash => { :error => "Team code invalid" }
    end
  end

  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      UserSession.create(user_id: current_user.id, login_time: DateTime.now, last_action_time: DateTime.now, num_team_members: params[:user][:num_team_members])

      root_path
    end
end
```

**user_model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
  has_many :readiness_factor_responses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_sessions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activity_plan_users, dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :username,
    presence: true,
    length: { minimum: 2 }

  attr_accessor :team_code
  attr_accessor :num_team_members
  attr_accessor :accept_terms


  def is_admin?
    self.admin
  end

  def step_and_substep
    [self.current_step, self.current_substep]
  end

  def current_session
    # weak way to handle the case where other teammates have signed up but not logged in
    if self.user_sessions
      self.user_sessions.order("created_at").last
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  # user is defined as idle if they haven't taken an action in 30 min. They will also be forced to reauth by devise
  def is_idle?
    if self.current_session && self.current_session.last_action_time
      (Time.now - self.current_session.last_action_time) > 1800
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your local machine in production mode?

Comment: Interesting idea - just tested it out, still getting correct behaviour locally, even in production mode...

Comment: Those db columns probably shouldn't have been nullable.

Comment: One thing I am noticing from your server output is that the user already exists, but then it looks to also recreate a user with that info.  Why are you recreating a user if they exist?  Might not be the solution to this exact issue, but it does appear that there are some odd things going on in your code.   Could you post the registrations controller code?

Comment: The user model might also be useful

Comment: Added registration_controller and user_model code, thanks. And yeah, I noticed that the only validation for the user model happens on the front end (I could add a migration to address this) - but I'd really like to know why this is happening...

Comment: touch tmp/restart.txt resolves the issue! However, it started occurring again several weeks later. So I can restart as a bandaid, but the underlying issue is still occurring.